# pgfplots: line sharp plot histogram - value is missing and values too much

Tags: pgfplots, statistics, histogram

I have values
`1 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6`

and want that to plot as a *line sharp plot histogram*.

So, I set:

```
hist={
handler/.style={sharp plot},
intervals=false,
},
```

But he does not want to show the 2 times of the number 6...

Then there is a strangeness: If I do not set `x filter/.expression={x==int(x) ? x : nan}` he shows rational values too with y=0, e.g. (x=0.5, y=0), what is correct, because there are no rationals in the list. 
And he does not know `xtick=data` here? 
*So this filter is a dumb trick and there should be a correct setting to show only the list-values.*

*€dit: By the way forgot to say, it could be that there is no number x=4 e.g. Then there should be a point (x=4, y=0) as well...*

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\pgfplotstableread[header=false]{
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
4
4
5
5
5
6
6
}\mydata

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
%xmin=0,  ruins the graph....
xmax=6,% works, but (x=6, y=2) still missing
ymax=5,  % works
xtick=data, % no effect
xticklabels={1,...,6}, % no effect
grid=both,
axis lines=middle,
title={x=6, y=2 is missing\dots},
]
\addplot+ [
hist={
%bins=6,
%  data min=1, %  no effect
%  data max=6, % no effect 
handler/.style={sharp plot},
intervals=false,
},
% How can I get rid of this:
x filter/.expression={x==int(x) ? x : nan}% strange, but without this filter rational x-values (with y=0) too.....
] table [y index=0] {\mydata};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't quite understand what the filter is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want 6 bins, where each bin should contain one integer value, which you get if set

```
  bins=6,
  data min=1, 
  data max=7,
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\pgfplotstableread[header=false]{
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
4
4
5
5
5
6
6
}\mydata

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  ymin=0, 
  grid=both,
  axis lines=middle,
  enlarge x limits,
  enlarge y limits={upper}
]
\addplot+ [
hist={
  bins=6,
  data min=1, 
  data max=7, 
  handler/.style={sharp plot},
  intervals=false
},
] table [y index=0] {\mydata};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice. :) ______________